# Increasing variable value progressively

Tags: actionscript-3

In ActionScript 3 i would like a variable to start from 0 and reach 100, increasing its value progressively by a `factor X`.

For example, it starts from `0` then raise fast to `50` and reach `100` gradually, slowly.

Imagine a parabola like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution:

```
parabola = (parabola *= 0.99) + 1;
```

Comment: Expression **parabola = parabola * 0.99 + 1;** will do the same without confusing anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just from playing with a graphing tool, a curve that somewhat resembles the one in your picture might be:

```
y = (-1000 / (x + 10)) + 100;
```